# Collecting Bluetooth Low Energy advertisements on a specific channel using android beacon library

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to android app programming and am building an app to collect Bluetooth Low Energy advertisements from multiple ibeacons. I am using the android beacon library for this purpose.
 [github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library](http://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)

My aim is to collect BLE advertisement on a specific channel (say channel 37). I am not able to figure out how this can be done using the library. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unusual to collect on a specific channel as most devices automatically use multiple channels. Are you sure you really need to do this? If you do, you are out of luck as neither the AltBeacon nor Android scanning libraries allow scanning on a specific channel. If you don't have to use Android, something like a sniffer might help:
https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/analysing-the-bluetooth-le-2-4ghz-spectrum/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Simon-Judge , I really appreciate it. The app I am developing is for conducting experiments and I only want to filter out the packets on a specific channel (that's an important prerequisite for the experiment). I have used the CC2540 packet sniffer by Texas instruments. I wish to do that using an Android smartphone. Can you suggest any hardware tweaks(if required) which can be done to obtain this specific functionality?

Comment: Sorry, this level of analysis isn't possible on Android